# Call PHP functions from html button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a php registration page that saves the user's data from a previous page to my database when the page first loads and also displays a button that directs the user to pay on an external site when they click it. I would like to edit the page to only save the data to the database when the user clicks the pay button. Can I have this button click event call a PHP function or PHP page to handle this processing and also have the user continue with payment on the external site? I'm using a paypal buy now button which is basically a form with hidden input values.  I'm guessing I have to use Ajax but I dont know how.

**EDIT**
Just to clarify what im trying to do. I want to temporarily save registration data to my database before they pay and once they pay that data will be transferred to another table so I know its finalized. I want to save the temp registration data when they click the pay button. The same page that has this pay button also saves the temp  registration data to the database on load. I want to change that so the data isnt saved until the user at least click to pay. otherwise if for some reason the user stops here I end up with a database full of incomplete registrations.

**Edit**
Here is my attempt but it doesn't seem to be working.

**tempregister1.php**

```
<?php

$fname=$_POST['fname];

echo' <!DOCTYPE html>  
  <html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script>
    $(#submitbtn).click(function() {

     var fname = '.$fname.';     
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "tempregister2.php",
      data: {fname:fname}
     })    
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
 <input type="image" name="submit" id="submitbtn" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" >
 </form>
 </body>
 </html> 
 '; //end php echo
 ?>
```

**tempregister2.php**

```
<?php

$fname=$_POST['fname']; 

require_once('db.php');
$conn = db_connect();

$result = $conn->prepare("INSERT into temp (FirstName) VALUES(?)");
$result -> bind_param('s',$fname);
$result->execute();

?>
```

**EDIT** 
Problem Solved:
I needed to add this before the script in tempregister1.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#submitbtn).submit(function() {
```

Not sure if it made a difference but I also change it from a click event to a submit event  and changed var fname = $('.$_POST['fname'].'); to var fname = '.$_POST['fname'].';
Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: You can't execute a PHP function with a button. What you can do is send a request to a URL on your server that executes the PHP function with the POST data it receives. This is the how the client-server model works.

Comment: I doubt you will need `AJAX` at all, with a `<form>` you will be redirected to Paypal site, pay, and then redirecting to site again. This is for simple, `<form>` made payments. But you talked about _processing_. Are you going to use Paypal IPN? You want to handle pre-order and after-order process like databases?

Comment: @vlzvl, yes I'm using IPN but thats afterward. Im trying handle the pre order process. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ajax for calling a php page function. You can pass data from HTML to PHP and then perform you desired action and redirect to any external site.

Send you data in this click function to PHP. you need to give Ids to HTML form field and then need to pick those in JavaScript function.

```
 $('.button').click(function() {
     var email= $('#email'); // example email field
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { name: "John" , email:email }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });    
});
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm new here. Trying to figure out how to post. As soon as I do I'll post my attempt.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?? any error

Comment: I didn't get an error. The page just went to the paypal site like it should but nothing was saved to the database. I posted what I tried above. Am I missing something?

Comment: var fname = $('.$_POST['fname'].');  this will not work in javascript code. this works in PHP. you have to do like var fname = $('#fname');

Comment: second do an echo of query and let me know what is output in firebug

Comment: This is a PHP not a html page. The registration form input is posted to this page from a previous page and I get the variable using fname=$_POST['fname].  Nothing is being inputted by the user on this page. All it has is a button that takes you to paypal. All the html and javascript are echoed in the PHP.

Comment: but this script is javascript: $(#submitbtn).click(function() {

var fname = $('.$_POST['fname'].');     
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tempregister2.php",
    data: { fname:fname}
  })    
});
</script>

Comment: here you cannot do $_POST but can only use jquery. if this not then please post the appropriate code because from this code ti is the only mistake seems in code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way I have the PHP. I figured out the problem. I needed to add this at the beginning  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' id='yourButton' value='Button' >
```

**AJAX (Using Jquery)** : [AJAX DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#yourButton').click(function(){ // Your Click Event here
$.ajax({

//your AJAX call here


      });



});
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

/*Your php Code goes here*/

?>
```